# Good printing effect for pattern packaging design

Tags: print-design, packaging

I am currently designing a tube for skincare products similar to this:

[image]

The design so far has repeated patterns on the tube kind of like this:

[image]

My team wants to use nude and cream color on a matte finish. I thought it would be hard to stand out.

I thought about using:

- 2 Metallic Inks, but pattern is small so it won't print well since matte paper will absorb the metallic inks
- using texture paper with foil...too expensive, company can't afford
- using UV on pattern, with matte paper? maybe?

What would you use for soft cream colors with pattern on a tube like this. (with limited budget?)

Comment: won't it be a good idea to avoid hard edges and use smooth curved lines

Answer (score -2):

Not wanting to be mean but, why are you showing pictures of things that look like other things, and then worry about if you stand out or not?

"What would you use for soft cream colors with pattern on a tube like this. (with limited budget?)"

The group of cans with metal lids is ugly, I wouldn't copy them at all. If you go to Google Images and type in "cream wallpaper" then almost anything looks better than those. So even wallpaper is more interesting, and you can just borrow their colors without using the whole design.

I don't know anything about make up but I bet you that if you put make up in a tea can it will look like tea no matter what.

Comment: I showed other design because that is what the team really likes. They are inspire by those design and wanted the tube design similar to that. Sometimes it kind of limited my creativity. However, I will google wallpaper and see what is out there! Thank you for your help!